# How to Handle 26-Byte Secret for Time-based One Time Password?

Tags: go, authentication, one-time-password, totp

Secret of Time-based One Time Password are usually 16-byte base32 encoded string. e.g. GitHub 2FA.

But for some scenario, it has 26 bytes long. e.g. Tutanota OTP. Often in lower case with whitespaces, like: `vev2 qjea un45 3sr4 q4h3 ais4 ci`

I tried with the TOTP algorithm implemented in [dgryski/dgoogauth](https://github.com/dgryski/dgoogauth) and [tilaklodha/google-authenticator](https://github.com/tilaklodha/google-authenticator). Both can handle 16-byte secret well, but got error for 26-byte secret.

e.g. for 16-byte secret `VEV2QJEAUN453SR4`:

```sh
Time: 2021-12-17 14:31:46
Got: 079119
```

for 26-byte secret `VEV2QJEAUN453SR4Q4H3AIS4CI`:

```sh
Error: "illegal base32 data at input byte 24"
```

Here's the code snippet:

```golang
func getHOTPToken(secret string, interval int64) (string, error) {
    // Converts secret to base32 Encoding
    key, err := base32.StdEncoding.DecodeString(secret)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Signing the value using HMAC-SHA1 Algorithm
    hash := hmac.New(sha1.New, key)
    err = binary.Write(hash, binary.BigEndian, uint64(interval))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    h := hash.Sum(nil)

    // Get 32 bit chunk from hash starting at the offset
    offset := h[19] & 0x0f
    truncated := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(h[offset : offset+4])
    truncated &= 0x7fffffff
    code := truncated % 1000000

    return fmt.Sprintf("%06d", code), nil
}
```

Can you please tell me how to handle 26-byte secret?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base32 encodes every 5 bits of input bytes into base32 character, go base32 use
The RFC 4648 Base 32 alphabet (A-Z, 2-7). When decode a string to bytes, each base32
character input will be mapped to a 5 bit index then recompose to bytes.

In your example "VEV2QJEAUN453SR4Q4H3AIS4CI", the previous "VEV2QJEAUN453SR4"
was already valid input, it is a 16 char input, and 5 bit * 16 is 80 bit so it can be resolved into 10 bytes output. Now let us just look at the rest "Q4H3AIS4CI",
10 char -> 5 * 10 = 50 bits, the previous 40 bits can be decode to 5 bytes, but the last 2 char "CI" leads 2 bit remainder

```
    Q    |    4    |    H    |    3    |    A    |    I    |    S    |    4    |   C     |    I
1 0 0 0 0|1 1 1 0 0|0 0 1 1 1|1 1 0 1 1|0 0 0 0 0|0 1 0 0 0|1 0 0 1 0|1 1 1 0 0|0 0 0 1 0|0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1|0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1|1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0|0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0|0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0|0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0|0 0
    135        |       15      |      176      |       34      |        92     |      18       |

    C    |     I   |    =    |    =    |    =    |    =    |    =    |    =    |
0 0 0 1 0|0 1 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0|
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
     18        |
```

You need to add 6 paddings
the remainder bit of multiples of 5 % 8 is:

```
                          Its bits are divisible every eight chars
bitwise opinion           byte opinion        padding chars
1 char: 5  % 8 = 5 bit  |  1 % 8 (char) = 1 -> 7 char
2 char: 10 % 8 = 2 bit  |  2 % 8 (char) = 2 -> 6 char (this case "CI")
3 char: 15 % 8 = 7 bit  |  3 % 8 (char) = 3 -> 5 char
4 char: 20 % 8 = 4 bit  |  4 % 8 (char) = 4 -> 4 char
5 char: 25 % 8 = 1 bit  |  5 % 8 (char) = 5 -> 3 char
6 char: 30 % 8 = 6 bit  |  6 % 8 (char) = 6 -> 2 char
7 char: 35 % 8 = 3 bit  |  7 % 8 (char) = 7 -> 2 char
8 char: 40 % 8 = 0 bit  |  8 % 8 (char) = 8 -> 0 char
```

I have modified your code, the inputs "Q4H3AIS4CI" with 6 padding is ok

```
func Base32Test() {
    // 8 char: 5 * 8 bits -> decodes to 5 bytes
    key, err := base32.StdEncoding.DecodeString("Q4H3AIS4")
    fmt.Println(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("test 1, ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("test 1 ok", key)
    }
    // 10 char: 5 * 10 bits -> decodes to 5 bytes and remaider (2 bits but the last 10 bits can not be decode)
    key, err = base32.StdEncoding.DecodeString("Q4H3AIS4CI")
    fmt.Println(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("test 2, ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("test 2 ok", key)
    }
    // padding
    key, err = base32.StdEncoding.DecodeString("Q4H3AIS4CI======")
    fmt.Println(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("test 3, ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("test 3 ok", key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Padding matters -- so it seems that I should add padding check, like this:
`if rmd := len(secret) * 5 % 8; rmd != 0 {
 secret += strings.Repeat("=", 8-rmd)
}`